# retrieving numerical index from an array in tcl

Tags: arrays, tcl

I'm trying to retrieve a list of numbers from an array (in a txt file) and to do mathematical operations on them then to set them back in a list of the same format.
The txt file looks like this (format is fixed):

```
1000 2000 3000 4000
```

I want to read that txt file then to create another list which will be saved in a different text file:

```
1010 1100 2010 2100 3010 3100 4010 40100 # which is basically adding 10 and 100 to each index.
```

Here what I've done so far (I'm a very beginner in tcl !)

```
set zonefile [open "mytxtfile.txt" r]
gets $zonefile
set my_list [gets $zonefile]
puts $my_list

# Check that there is at least one location defined
if { [llength $my_list] == 0 } {
    error "No domain are defined in the system parameters workbook"
} else {
    puts "OK !"
}
puts [llength my_list]

# this returns 1, which from my understanding means I only have 1 value in my array instead of 4
set c1 [string range $my_list 0 3]
set c2 [string range $my_list 5 8]
set c3 [string range $my_list 10 13]
set c4 [string range $my_list 15 18]
array set domain_list ([lindex $c1 0] [lindex $c2 0])
# I thought this would create an array of 1000 2000 3000 4000 but this doesn't work
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need to know indexes of elements at all, just use `foreach` and `lappend` to build the output array:

```
set in [open input.txt r]
set a {}
foreach n [split [read $in] " "] {
    lappend a [expr {$n + 10}] [expr {$n + 100}]
}
close $in
set out [open output.txt w]
puts $out $a
close $out
```

If input.txt is:

```
1000 2000 3000 4000
```

output.txt will be

```
1010 1100 2010 2100 3010 3100 4010 4100
```

Comment: @flavie, note the use of `split` here -- not every string can be safely treated as a list, so best to code defensively.

Comment: It is working ! I just forgot to mention that my list of numbers was starting on the line 2 (I have a header on line 1). Just now need to start the reading form line 2 and add my header in the output file. Thanks and sorry for my stupidity !